# Lookup table Fast Sigmoidal function

Tags: java

```
private static double [] sigtab = new double[1001];  // values of f(x) for x values 

static {
  for(int i=0; i<1001; i++) {
      double ifloat = i;
      ifloat /= 100;
      sigtab[i] = 1.0/(1.0 + Math.exp(-ifloat));
  }
}

public static double fast_sigmoid (double x) {
    if (x <= -10)
        return 0.0;
    else if (x >= 10)
        return 1.0;
    else {
        double normx = Math.abs(x*100);
        int i = (int)normx;
        double lookup = sigtab[i] + (sigtab[i+1] - sigtab[i])*(normx - Math.floor(normx));
        if (x > 0)
            return lookup;
        else // (x < 0)
            return (1 - lookup);
    }
}
```

Anyone know why this "fast sigmoid" actually runs slower than the exact version using Math.exp?

Answer (score 2):

You should profile your code, but I'll bet it's the call to `Math.floor` taking around half your CPU cycles (it is slow because it calls the native method `StrictMath.floor(double)`, incurring the JNI overhead.)

It *is* possible to compute (less-accurate) versions of sigmoid functions faster than the (exact) hardware implementations.  Here's an example for `tanh`, which should be easy to transform to your function (is it `expit(-x)`?)

Two tricks that are used here are often useful in LUT-based approximations:

- Simulate rounding by adding a large constant (forcing the FPU will truncate it, having too few bits to represent the sum)
- Make your table size a power of 2 (means one less multiply per call)

```
public static float fastTanH(float x) {
    if (x<0) return -fastTanH(-x);
    if (x>8) return 1f;
    float xp = TANH_FRAC_BIAS + x;
    short ind = (short) Float.floatToRawIntBits(xp);
    float tanha = TANH_TAB[ind];
    float b = xp - TANH_FRAC_BIAS;
    x -= b;
    return tanha + x * (1f - tanha*tanha);
}

private static final int TANH_FRAC_EXP = 6; // LUT precision == 2 ** -6 == 1/64
private static final int TANH_LUT_SIZE = (1 << TANH_FRAC_EXP) * 8 + 1;
private static final float TANH_FRAC_BIAS =
    Float.intBitsToFloat((0x96 - TANH_FRAC_EXP) << 23);
private static float[] TANH_TAB = new float[TANH_LUT_SIZE];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < TANH_LUT_SIZE; ++ i) {
        TANH_TAB[i] = (float) Math.tanh(i / 64.0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, if you disagree about `Math.floor` being a bottleneck, [here's an explanation](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6908131).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean looking up in an array of double elements and performing some calculus should be faster than calculating it on the spot?

Altough the CPU only has basic operations, it can handle an exponentiation pretty easily. I'd say in less than 5 basic operations.

What you are doing here is somehow complex and requires actually having to go fetch some elements in the memory. 64bits*1001 surely fits in your cache but cache access time certainly does not match registry access time.

This case does not surprise me in the least.